# Stepwise and time & individual/country fixed effects panels in Stata with appropriate s.e. adjustment

Tags: stata

I want to run `stepwise` on a linear probability model with time and individual fixed effects in a panel dataset but `stepwise` does not support panels out of the box. The solution is to to run `xtdata y x, fe` followed by `reg y x, r` . However, the resulting standard errors are too small. One attempt to solve this problem can be found here: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-07/msg00629.html but my panel is highly unbalanced (I have a different number of observations for different variables). I also don't understand how stepwise would include this information in its iterations with different variable lists. Since stepwise bases its decision rules on the pvals, this is quite crucial.

**Reproducible Example:**

```
webuse nlswork, clear /*unbalancing a bit:*/
replace tenure =. if year <73
replace hours =. if hours==24 | hours==38
replace tenure =. if idcode==3 | idcode == 12 | idcode == 19

xtreg ln_wage tenure hours union i.year, fe vce(robust)
eststo xtregit /*this is what I want to reproduce without xtreg to use it in stepwise */

xi i.year /* year dummies to keep */
xtdata ln_wage tenure hours union _Iyear*, fe clear

reg ln_wage tenure hours union _Iyear*, vce(hc3) /*regression on transformed data */
eststo regit
esttab xtregit regit
```

As you can see, the estimates are fine but I need to adjust the standard errors. Also, I need to do that in such a way that `stepwise` understands in its iterations when the number of variables changes, for example. Any help on how to proceed?

Comment: This seems as much statistical as a programming question. I would ask on Statalist.

Comment: Thanks, done. Though statistically the question is quite straightforward: how do I get the degree of freedom adjustment (eg Wooldridges Panelbook, 2012, p. 308) into stepwise? What I have to do here in order to use stepwise is to run a dummy variable regression on within-transformed data. The question is mainly: How can I tell Stata and mainly stepwise about that? I should also note that the problem is not limited to time fixed effects. Omit "i.year" and the dummies and you'll have the same problem.

Comment: `stepwise` is a bad idea any way! (The discussion could go on.)

Comment: granted, but it should still work on a mechanical level.